# Win7 Screen Cap to Realtime Video Driver?

Tags: windows-7, video, screen-capture, drivers

Back in the ancient days of XP, I had a program (the name escapes me) that would allow you to specify a section of screen or the active area of a window the realtime content of which would then be provided to the operating system as a video source, so you could use the screen content as if it were a camera.

Does this ring a bell with anyone?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a virtual DirectShow video capture device that takes a screengrab as input.  Try this one:  http://www.umediaserver.net/umediaserver/download.html
If that doesn't work for you, this might be helpful: http://betterlogic.com/roger/2010/07/list-of-available-directshow-screen-capture-filters/